# 500 interal error when deploying GCP website with Flask

Tags: google-app-engine, web, flask, google-cloud-platform

I've finish a website that run correct localy (VScode with live server).

I use HTML/CSS/JScript with python Flask, sqlalchemy and werkzeug.

The file system is compounded of:

static (img / data.db / style.css)

templates ( layout.html + all html files)

main.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
from functools import wraps
from sqlalchemy import update, select, MetaData, insert, Text, Table, Column, Integer, Numeric, String, create_engine
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = X

# access DB
metadata = MetaData()
users = Table('users', metadata,
              Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
              Column('username', Text(50), index=True),
              Column('hash', Text()),
              Column('mon_o', Text(5)),
              Column('mon_c', Text(5)),
              Column('tue_o', Text(5)),
              Column('tue_c', Text(5)),
              Column('wed_o', Text(5)),
              Column('wed_c', Text(5)),
              Column('thu_o', Text(5)),
              Column('thu_c', Text(5)),
              Column('fri_o', Text(5)),
              Column('fri_c', Text(5)),
              Column('sat_o', Text(5)),
              Column('sat_c', Text(5)),
              Column('closed', Text(100)),
              Column('other', Text(100))
              )
# create engine for SQLite DB
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///P:\Code\WEB\RML\static\data.db')
# activate engines
metadata.create_all(engine)


def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get("user_id") is None:
            return redirect("/")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function





@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Get DB
    connection = engine.connect()
    query = select([users]).where(users.c.id == 1)
    rp = connection.execute(query)
    result = rp.fetchall()
    first_row = result[0]
    return render_template("index.html", variable=first_row)


@app.route("/map")
def map():
    return render_template("map.html")


@app.route("/contact")
def rdv():
    return render_template("contact.html")


# form RDV
@app.route("/form")
def form():
    return render_template("form.html")
#


@app.route('/email')
def email():
    return render_template("email.html")


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    # clear id session
    session.clear()

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")

    else:  # POST
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return render_template("index.html")
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return render_template("index.html")

        connection = engine.connect()

        # read DB
        query = select([users])
        rp = connection.execute(query)
        result = rp.fetchall()
        # check password
        if (not check_password_hash(result[0][users.c.hash], request.form.get("password"))) or (not (result[0][users.c.username]) == (request.form.get("username"))):
            return render_template("index.html")
        else:
            # session = user row value = id
            session["user_id"] = result[0]["id"]
            return render_template("upgrade.html")


# Form upgrade with decorator
@app.route("/upgrade", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upgrade():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("upgrade.html")
    else:  # POST

        id = session['user_id']

        # access DB
        sql = update(users).where(users.c.id == id)
        sql = sql.values(mon_o=request.form.get('mon_o'),
                         mon_c=request.form.get('mon_c'),
                         tue_o=request.form.get('tue_o'),
                         tue_c=request.form.get('tue_c'),
                         wed_o=request.form.get('wed_o'),
                         wed_c=request.form.get('wed_c'),
                         thu_o=request.form.get('thu_o'),
                         thu_c=request.form.get('thu_c'),
                         fri_o=request.form.get('fri_o'),
                         fri_c=request.form.get('fri_c'),
                         sat_o=request.form.get('sat_o'),
                         sat_c=request.form.get('sat_c'),
                         closed=request.form.get('closed'),
                         other=request.form.get('other')
                         )

        connection = engine.connect()
        # insert the statement into the DB
        result = connection.execute(sql)
        return render_template("index.html", variable=result[0])
```

layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4abbdb9d0.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- add font family -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- OSM -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
      crossorigin=""
    />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw=="
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" />
    <title>Radiologie Mont Lucas</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    {% block body %} {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

requirements.txt:

```
# requirement for rml app.py
gunicorn==19.9.0
sqlalchemy==1.3.11
werkzeug==0.16.0
jinja2==2.10.3
flask==1.1.1
```

I've push from local to github

Then from github to GCP:

new project => open in terminal

git clone

cd projectname

pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt

gcloud init

gcloud app deploy

gcloud app browse

No error but when I open the browser I get:

Browser:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Browser console:

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

I've try all the day different kind of tuto but I found nothing clear. The last thing I've done is modify the app.yaml (and add gunicorn in requirements.txt).

I'm not sure what I've done with gunicorn.

I've read something about some https request that fail because my web site is http. But I'm really not sure.

I don't know where to go in order to deploy my flask web app in GCP.

Edit: adding the error code:
IndexError: list index out of range at index (/home/vmagent/app/main.py:59) at dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1935) at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1949) at reraise (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39) at handle_user_exception (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1820) at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1951) at wsgi_app (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:2446)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does Stackdriver show you any errors?

Comment: Hello, ```
IndexError: list index out of range

        at index (/home/vmagent/app/main.py:59)
        at dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1935)
        at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1949)
        at reraise (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39)
        at handle_user_exception (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1820)
        at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1951)
        at wsgi_app (/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:2446)

```

Comment: @saquiel that error message is quite essential, can you add it as a part of your question maybe?

Comment: and it also tells what exactly is your problem - `first_row = result[0]` while the `result` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the traceback says what the problem is:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Get DB
    connection = engine.connect()
    query = select([users]).where(users.c.id == 1)
    rp = connection.execute(query)
    result = rp.fetchall()
    first_row = result[0] # <- here you're trying to get 1st element \
    # but the the `result` is empty -> IndexError
```

In order to avoid this error you have to check if the collection is not empty before trying to work with its elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot but why all is working on localhost (liveserver) and fail on a GCP ?

Comment: your DB on localhost have presumably some data in it, unlike the GCP database

Comment: I've remove the DB (SQLite) and change for local data (array). Go a lot of other problems (server unreable, command that never stop) until I've try from my home. In fact, the network at work was charged (UDP trafic overload by fools). It's seems that the connection with GCP was parasited by our overloaded network. Now the app run well. Just need some finishing touch. Thanks to all for your answers.